# Modify scope variable

Tags: php, angularjs

I had a string variable in php with this value `000001422` and I used to modify it in order to display it in a better way:

```
<?php
$hits = "000001422";
$var = (int)$hits;
$var = abbreviateNumber($var);
echo $var; ?>
```

This is the function to crop and abbreviate the number in something like `1,4k`

```
function abbreviateNumber(value) {
    var newValue = value;
    if (value >= 1000) {
        var suffixes = ["", "k", "m", "b","t"];
        var suffixNum = Math.floor( (""+value).length/3 );
        var shortValue = '';
        for (var precision = 2; precision >= 1; precision--) {
            shortValue = parseFloat( (suffixNum != 0 ? (value / Math.pow(1000,suffixNum) ) : value).toPrecision(precision));
            var dotLessShortValue = (shortValue + '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
            if (dotLessShortValue.length <= 2) { break; }
        }
        if (shortValue % 1 != 0)  shortNum = shortValue.toFixed(1);
        newValue = shortValue+suffixes[suffixNum];
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

This worked great.

Now I'm trying to switch my code to AngularJS (I'm still learning it) so my value it's not a php variable but a scope variable received from an $http request. I have something like `{{x.count}}` which is my `000001422` but I would like to display it in the same way I did before.

I tryed to `$hits = "{{x.count}}";` but it's not working and I think it's not the right approach. Can you address me in the right way to handle this?

**EDIT:**

I removed the initial zeros converting the value into an int with `{{x.count - 0}}` but still need to apply my abbreviate function.

Comment: You can't call PHP code from JS (unless you use something like Ajax but that would be overkill), so you'll need to rewrite your `abbreviateNumber` in JS.

Comment: @this.lau_ Is it possible to store the scope variable and edit it as I did before with js?